# wxWidgets wxVector Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, wxwidgets

I have problem with sort vector. I have code like below and i dont understand why this funcion sort dont sorting my vector. I also tried wxVectorSort and also dont work

```
wxTextFile file( wxT("myfile.txt") );
    wxString text;
    wxVector<wxString> fileLines;

  wxString pobierz;


        file.Open();
        for(size_t i=0; i<file.GetLineCount(); i++){
            text << file.GetLine(i)<< wxT("\n");
            fileLines.push_back(text);

        }
        file.Close();

 sort(fileLines.begin(), fileLines.end());



 for (wxVector<wxString>::iterator it = fileLines.begin() ; it != fileLines.end(); ++it){

     TextCtrl_wczytaj->SetValue(*it);
 }
```

Can someone give some advices how to sort this vector? Ty for any answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you refer to sorting numbers, as in "11" vs "2" (like in this very similar wxWidgets forum [post](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=47798&p=202604)), you can try with [`wxSortedArrayString`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_sorted_array_string.html) and one of the available [sorting functions](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/arrstr_8h.html):

- `wxStringSortAscending`
- `wxDictionaryStringSortAscending`
- `wxNaturalStringSortAscending`
  (and their *`Descending` counterparts)
- `wxCmpNatural`
- `wxCmpNaturalGeneric`

  ```
    wxSortedArrayString sas(wxNaturalStringSortAscending);

    sas.Add("2");
    sas.Add("11");
    sas.Add("3");
    // final order is {"2", "3", "11"}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Also, keep in mind that it is strngly suggested t use std::vector, std::list, etc vs their wx counterparts.

wx container classes are there for backward compatibility and it is preferred to not use them in the newly written code